# Jest await not working/returning anything test is frozen

Tags: jestjs

I am trying to use await in my test and when I run the test runner the test becomes stuck and no test result is returned. Here is my code

```
describe("retrieveCandidate", () => {
  describe("when settings are found", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      configurationApi = new ConfigurationApi(BaseUrl);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      configurationApi = undefined;
    });
    it("should return set of configuration values", () => {
       const configurationValueSet: IConfigurationValueSet | undefined =
         await configurationApi?.retrieveCandidate(controlConfigurationValueSet.specializationKey);
      expect(true).toEqual(true);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

So in my testsetup file I had

```
jest.useFakeTimers();
```

This caused my async functions to never return anything and caused my test to be in a frozen state